# Can we use ftp in place of tftp in pxe boot

Tags: ftp, kickstart, pxe, tftp

Tftp is used to get OS image from pxe server to client as it uses UDP for file transfer. But can we use ftp for the same. If yes then how and if no then why?

Comment: You can't, because the TFTP protocol is different from the FTP protocol, and PXE clients only support TFTP (because it's less complex than FTP, note the "trivial" in TFTP). Of course you can write your own BIOS with your own PXE client which does support FTP ... but then it'll still only work on computers with your custom BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes you can... you'll *just* need to design a PXE standard extension for FTP, then write a new netboot firmware to implement that extension, then flash it to your NICs.

In practice, it's probably not worth of the effort unless you have a very hard requirement for FTP specifically.

But before you start that development project, note that [iPXE](https://ipxe.org) can use HTTP. You can either use TFTP-based PXE to load iPXE as your first-stage network bootloader, and then have it switch to HTTP for speed, or - if your NIC is supported by the iPXE project - get iPXE in a flashable format and flash it into your NIC, and then use HTTP for all netboot-related file transfers.